# Write a MIB file that defines entire

Tags: snmp, oid, mib, windows-event-log

I am attempting to configure event log monitoring to snmp trap "service" on Windows Server.

See: [How do I passively monitor the Windows Event Log?](https://serverfault.com/questions/22489/how-do-i-passively-monitor-the-windows-event-log) & http://www.eric-a-hall.com/articles/20050715.html

The front-end for snmptt I use (Centreon) requires a MIB import for it to happily generate snmptt.conf file(s).  This point can be mostly disregarded in effort to obtain an answer to my question:

How do I write a MIB file that contains a "wildcard" for all OIDs "below" a certain OID?

I came across simply adding .0 to this, but during testing, it does not seem to work.

Here is more info on configuring snmptt: http://wiki.nagios.org/index.php/Howtos:snmp-windows

Comment: This is still of interest, but instead of struggling, I'm going to use a nagios plugin with nsclient++ to handle the task at hand.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? There may be (free) products out there that can accomplish this. Are you trying to collect Windows event logs via SNMP?

Comment: I was trying to monitor event logs, and using the native  SNMP stuff offered by Microsoft, the OID of each trap sent are some of the contents of a the given event.  You could handle the above condition with a script tied into `snmptt`.  But [it's much easier to use nsclient++](https://mbrownnyc.wordpress.com/2011/08/26/descriptive-and-granular-event-log-monitoring-with-nsclient-and-nagios-2/)